# How can I use Facebook Graph API to get my site's recommendations?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to add a like/recommendation button to my site.  Then, I want to be able to use the Graph API to query the recommendations for my domain (e.g. 17 people liked mysite.com/thisawesomepage)

There is a plugin that does this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations,
but I want to be able to retrieve the raw data.

Is this possible?

Comment: you mean this plugin: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: No, I want to get the data AFTER people have liked/recommended using the plugin at the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need the 'like_id' of your site.  you can get it by liking it and looking at your list of likes through the graph api or however else.

then you just put it in a url like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/125086767519561

125086767519561 is the id of the The Glamourist, and you can see that it has been liked 198 times at the time of this writing.

Comment: Right, I understand that.  But how can I get more information about who liked it?  For example: https://graph.facebook.com/161820597180936/likes - If I do this to yours I just get an empty dataset: https://graph.facebook.com/125086767519561/likes

Comment: im almost positive that you can not get that.  who likes what is private data to that person (as in they need to auth your app for you to know).  so you can't even take the scraped 250mil user list and check against which ones liked your site.

Comment: Yes, after looking around some more I would need them to authorize my website to get to that data.  Thank you, Kalendae, for your responses!  Cheers.