# Facebook Graph Api to read recommendations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

While I can access several data using fbgraph api, I couldn't find way to read the "recommendations" data.

For example: For the facebook page www.facebook.com/cozycaterers , its recommendation content appearing on right side below cover photo.

Could someone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what is meant by recommendation for your app?

Comment: U see this facebook page www.facebook.com/cozycaterers. I need to get "Recommendations" part through facebook graph API.

Comment: Two similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598128/how-can-i-use-facebook-graph-api-to-get-my-sites-recommendations, http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10241440/facebook-recommendations-box-data-thorugh-php-sdk

Comment: CBroe: those are unrelated - I think OP is asking about the new Recommendations functionality for places/pages - i don't know the answer to their question - i'm not sure there is an api for it

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is currently possible.

I have checked the Docs for FQL and Graph API with no luck ...

Hopefully facebook will allow access sooner or later

Answer (score 0):

I tried this query with the [FQL Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer):

```
SELECT review_id, rating, message, reviewer_id FROM review where reviewee_id='492378670299'
```

It returned results, but not as many as I expected.

If anyone has a better answer, I'd be happy to know...